# Error: Argument of \newcommand{...} has an extra }

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, errors, hyperref, urls

I am trying to create a new command to help formatting the entries of the list of figures. Argument 1 should be optional and contain the date the source was accessed, argument 2 is simply the figure's caption I want to show up in the list of figures, and argument 3 is a hyperlink to the source of the image. I want the source and date to only show up in the list of figures and not underneath the actual image. I wrote this in the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\lof}[3][]{
\textbf{#2}
\linebreak
{\scriptsize #3 #1}
}
```

This is the caption of some figure:

```
\caption[
\lof[(Accessed on 02.01.2019)]
{Basic neural network with three layers}
{\url{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Artificial_neural_network.svg}}
]
{Basic neural network with three layers}
```

Note that I want to be able to declare that the image is my own, in which case the hyperlink and the date should be omitted.

```
\caption[
{Basic neural network with three layers}
{Made by the author.}
]
{Basic neural network with three layers}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
! Argument of \\lof has an extra }.
```

However, the brackets should be balanced if I am not completely mistaken. I have read somewhere that there are 'fragile' commands, and using them leads to the same error message I got. Might \url{} be a fragile command? Or have I messed up the command definition somehow?

**Edit**:

The following code shows everything that might be related to the problem. If I remove these parts from the code, the LaTeX documents compiles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,graphicx,amsmath,hyperref}

\newcommand{\lof}[3][]{\textbf{#2}\newline {\scriptsize #3 #1}}
\begin{document}

 \listoffigures

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.25\textwidth} 
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption[ {\lof[(Accessed on 02.01.2019)] 
{Basic neural network with three layers}
{\url{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Artificial_neural_network.svg}}} ] 
{Basic neural network with three layers}
\label{fig:nn}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{wrapfigure}{h}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption[{\lof{$\boldsymbol{\sigma (x)}$, the sigmoid function}
{Created by the author}}]
{$\sigma (x)$, the sigmoid function}
\label{fig:sigmoid}
\end{wrapfigure} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\caption[
{\lof[(Accessed on 02.01.2019)]
{Basic neural network with three layers}
{\url{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Artificial_neural_network.svg}}}
]
{Basic neural network with three layers}` -- you must enclose the `\lot[...]{}{}` command with a `{}` pair, since it has an optional argument and occurs in the  optional argument of `\caption`

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SE of course ;-)

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `xparse` package, which makes it considerably easier to define commands with multiple optonal arguments.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem. I get the same error message as before. And thank you :)

Comment: @Terrenay: Then add the complete code, not just fragments only

Comment: The `\newline` does look unhealthy to me...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have replaced it with \linebreak, but the error persists.

Comment: unrelated to the error but you are missing `%` in your definitions, and size commands do not take an argument so `\scriptsize{#3 #1}` would make all text following `\lof` be script size, not just `#3` and `'#1`

Comment: please always provide a test file that may be used to reproduce the error, your fragment is missing `\documentclass` and missing definitions of macros used

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, I have changed it to {\scriptsize #3 #1}

Comment: With the last version of the example code I only get the warning about colliding `wrapfigure` environments.

Comment: As you are new, I extended your fragment with the missing definitions and replacing with generally available images, however it does **not** produce the error that you are asking about. Please edit the example so that it is an example of the error.

Comment: Now, that the document is complete: It compiles for me with the `{}` pair around the `\lol` - macro call

Comment: also you should delete your .aux and .lof files which may be corrupted by previous errors.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! I have been trying to create a MWE but this only led to more unrelated errors... Now it compiles as expected and the error is solved. Thank you both for your help. I will have to look at what went wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get no error, but your input is very awkward and error prone.

I suggest to define a new `\xcaption` command, so as to minimize the burden.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xcaption}{O{#2}mmo}{%
  \caption[\lof{#1}{#3\IfValueT{#4}{ #4}}]{#2}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\lof}{mm}{%
  {\boldmath\textbf{#1}}\newline
  {\scriptsize #2}%
}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.25\textwidth} 
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
\xcaption
  {Basic neural network with three layers}
  {\url{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Artificial_neural_network.svg}}
  [(Accessed on 02.01.2019)]
\label{fig:nn}
\end{wrapfigure}

\kant[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{h}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\xcaption
  [Short caption with $\sigma(x)$]
  {$\sigma (x)$, the sigmoid function}
  {Created by the author}
\label{fig:sigmoid}
\end{wrapfigure} 

\kant[1]

\end{document}
```

The syntax is

```
\xcaption
  [<optional caption for the lof>]
  {<main caption>}
  {<attribution>}
  [<optional info>]
```

I added an example of the optional caption, also showing how to get bold math without explicitly adding `\boldsymbol`.

The `\lof` command is only auxiliary and it shouldn't be really used in the document.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a really smooth way to do it! I did not know about \NewDocumentCommand until now. For some reason though, I had to change the order of the arguments to [short caption]{main caption}[additional]{attribution}, supposedly because the optional argument in the last slot was not seen as part of the command anymore. (Accessed on) was printed right underneath the image's main caption and not in the list of figures.